# Reload page after 3 seconds with a promise in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, timeout, reload

I'm trying to implement a solution for the login page. When user passes the wrong login/password I want the page to reload after 3 seconds. I was trying to do it with 2 solutions but can't make it work. The code would launch after click on a button when there is no match for credentials `(else condition)`:

FIRST IDEA:

```
  ...else{
    this.comUser = 'WRONG LOGIN OR PASSWORD'
    this.alert = ""
    setTimeout(function() { 
      window.location = "I would like it to use the routing to a component instead of URL here"; }
      ,3000);
```

SECOND IDEA WITH A PROMISE:

```
const reloadDelay = () => {
  reload = this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("działa");
    resolve(reload)
    }, 4000);
  });
};
```

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: In the good old days, we'd use a nice simple [Meta Refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using angular 9 you can try this

```
setTimeout(() => {this.domDocument.location.reload()}, 3000);
```

You need to import:

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
```

In order to use the above-mentioned method and have the constructor of `component.ts` configured as below.

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private domDocument: Document){}
```

Comment: Thanks - seems logical but I'm getting an error: ERROR in src/app/login/login.component.ts:16:16 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Inject'.

16   constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document, private router: Router,private timeoutService: TimeoutService, private connectionService: ConnectionService) {
                  ~~~~~~

Comment: please update @angular/core import and include ```Inject```.  ```import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from "@angular/core";``` sorry my bad forgot to mention that.

Comment: It works exactly as planned - thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

This can now be done using the onSameUrlNavigation property of the Router config. In your router config enable `onSameUrlNavigation` option, setting it to `reload` . This causes the Router to fire an events cycle when you try to navigate to a route that is active already.

```
@ngModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
 exports: [RouterModule],
 })
```

In your route definitions, set `runGuardsAndResolvers` to always. This will tell the router to always kick off the guards and resolvers cycles, firing associated events.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: 'invites',
   component: InviteComponent,
   children: [
     {
       path: '',
       loadChildren: './pages/invites/invites.module#InvitesModule',
     },
   ],
   canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
   runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
 }
]
```

Finally, in each component that you would like to enable reloading, you need to handle the events. This can be done by importing the router, binding onto the events, and invoking an initialization method that resets the state of your component and re-fetches data if required.

```
export class InviteComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 navigationSubscription;     

 constructor(
   // … your declarations here
   private router: Router,
 ) {
   // subscribe to the router events. Store the subscription so we can
   // unsubscribe later.
   this.navigationSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((e: any) => {
     // If it is a NavigationEnd event re-initalise the component
     if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
       this.initialiseInvites();
     }
   });
 }

 initialiseInvites() {
   // Set default values and re-fetch any data you need.
 }

 ngOnDestroy() {
   if (this.navigationSubscription) {
     this.navigationSubscription.unsubscribe();
   }
 }
}
```

With all of these steps in place, you should have route reloading enabled. Now for your timeperiod, you can simply use settimeout on route.navigate and this should reload it after desired time.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation - I will surely try it, but can you please explain how to exactly set this timeout on route.navigate? I'm fighting with this :) Thanks in advance!